# Как запретить индексацию с get параметром "?url"?

Tags: robots.txt

Как запретить индексацию с get параметром "?url" в Robots.txt

То есть чтобы всё после `?url` **не индексировалось**

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества, вопрос правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я Вас верно понял, то попробуйте написать robots.txt следующее:

```
Disallow: /*?url
```